# Placeholder width function throws Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm a newbie on Js and I can not identify the source of the error:

I'm using a function to auto adjust the size of the inputs fields to the size of the placeholders; the code works fine *afaik* but dev tools tell me the "*Cannot read property 'length' of null"*

I'm kind of lost on this: I tried to change the type of data (JSON) with no success, check if there is something related with elements ID; I already take a look on some similar questions without been able to identify the culprit.

[This is a fiddle of the actual code](http://jsfiddle.net/nacionarte/17k2pmmy/1/)

```
var input = document.querySelectorAll('input');
for(i=0; i<input.length; i++){
   input[i].setAttribute('size',input[i].getAttribute('placeholder').length);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`radio` buttons don't have a placeholder, so `getAttribute('placeholder')` returns `null`.

You need to adjust your selector to only grab `input[type='text']` (or to be super safe, `input[placeholder]`).

Comment: Thanks for the information Mathletics, I replace the selector as you said and the error is gone. Amazing. Thanks again ;)